# how to disable laravel 5.4 default error handler

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am currently working on a laravel project. I need to redirect all error pages to 404 page not found page.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
        {
            if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
                switch ($exception->getStatusCode()) {

                        // not authorized
                        case '403':
                                return \Response::view('404',array(),403);
                                break;

                        // not found
                        case '404':
                                return \Response::view('404',array(),404);
                                break;

                        // internal error
                        case '500':
                                return \Response::view('404',array(),500);
                                break;

                        default:
                                return $this->renderHttpException($exception);
                                break;
                }
        } else {
                return parent::render($request, $exception);
        }



                return parent::render($request, $exception);
        }
```

Is there anyway to redirect error page to 404 page?. Also the validation errors are not displaying in this code(Redirecting to 404 when validation errors occurs). I am using the version 5.4.

Comment: have you try this method, return abort(404);

Comment: thanks for the comment.
already checked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its Bug of Laravel 5.4  modified on laravel 5.5

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/18481

change file vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
if (! $this->isHttpException($e) && config('app.debug')) {
        return $this->toIlluminateResponse($this->convertExceptionToResponse($e), $e);
    }
    if (! $this->isHttpException($e)) {
       return \Response::view('404',array(),500);
    }
    return $this->toIlluminateResponse($this->renderHttpException($e), $e);
```

Comment: Welcome @AneeshAjithkumar

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
    abort(404);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a directory in `resources/views/errors`

In this directory create files

`404.blade.php` for 404 error.

`500.blade.php` for 400 error.

`403.blade.php` for 403 error.

These views will be automatically rendered.
 for aborting application you can use `abort(404)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Already have these blades in my project like you described..but not showing the validations errors in pages.

Comment: make sure your web routes are in `web` middleware

Answer (score 1):

check if the code below is in "handler.php"

"use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;"

and check error resource file.
( https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-do-i-create-a-custom-404-error-page )

and you can use abort function in your handler